# Practice Exam Databricks Certified Data Engineer Associate - Question 40

Tags: databricks-connect, databricks-sql

Why option B is not the answer for this question?

> Question 40
>
> A data analyst has noticed that their Databricks SQL queries are
> running too slowly. They claim that this issue is affecting all of
> their sequentially run queries. They ask the data engineering team for
> help. The data engineering team notices that each of the queries uses
> the same SQL endpoint, but the SQL endpoint is not used by any other
> user. Which of the following approaches can the data engineering team
> use to improve the latency of the data analyst’s queries?
>
> A. They can turn on the Serverless feature for the SQL endpoint.
>
> B. They can increase the maximum bound of the SQL endpoint’s scaling
> range.
>
> **C. They can increase the cluster size of the SQL endpoint.**
>
> D. They can turn on the Auto Stop feature for the SQL endpoint.
>
> E. They can turn on the Serverless feature for the SQL endpoint and
> change the Spot Instance Policy to “Reliability Optimized.”

[This is the link for the practice exam](https://files.training.databricks.com/assessments/practice-exams/PracticeExam-DataEngineerAssociate.pdf?_ga=2.185796329.1103386439.1663221490-957565140.1661854848)

Comment: The same can be asked about options A/D/E. Why did you consider only option B?

Comment: Or in other words: it might help to get you a better answer to know why you thought B *might* be the answer.

Comment: Because to improve the performance of the query we need to upscale(B/C). Other options did not sound like upscaling to me

Comment: @Adrian, why -1 for this question

Comment: Sorry to say this, but some people were very keen to "discipline" me. Well, they should show at least half of that interest to contribute towards the solution also.

Comment: I didn't downvote (or try to "discipline" you), just suggest ways to help you get an answer.   That's one way to contribute towards a solution.  I didn't write an answer because I don't know the answer; I do know what sort of questions tend to get good answers, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- At here we have two things to decide which is the right choice:

1. There has got no other user sharing the same cluster
2. The queries are sequentially running.

- D is not right choice.
- We see that three answers A, B, E have the same idea aiming to scale out the number of clusters. The choices will solve the bottle-neck when sharing the clusters for many users. They are not right for their problem.
- Their queries are sequentially running so they need more powerful cluster to run.

**=> In my opinion, the C is the best option in the case.**